# Utils.bitmapToMat crashing app

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to convert a bmp file into a Mat, and then convert it to greyscale. But I'm having trouble getting it working. Here's what I've got:

```
String filename = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/01.bmp";    
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
Mat imgToProcess = null;

Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, imgToProcess);
```

But whenever that final line is used, the app just crashes (the rest of the time it continues on just fine).

The rest of the code was going to be:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(imgToProcess, imgToProcess, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.cvtColor(imgToProcess, imgToProcess, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
Utils.matToBitmap(imgToProcess, bmp);
```

I've no idea whether or not that works though, since I can't get the file converted to a Mat yet from the earlier part of the code. Looking at the documentation for Utils (found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/android/Utils.html)) I'm using it correctly, but it's still not working.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: And what is logcat output?

Comment: The file is on my phone... logcat basically says:
    12-11 16:38:04.834: E/AndroidRuntime(540): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bmp == null

Comment: just edit your question and take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Change line:

```
Mat imgToProcess = null;
```

to this:

```
Mat imgToProcess = new Mat();
```

or this:

```
 Mat imgToProcess = new Mat(bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
```

---

And why don't you just use [`Highgui.imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html#imread%28java.lang.String%29) instead?

```
Mat imgToProcess = Highgui.imread(filename);
```

Comment: I tried just those two lines:  String filename = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/01.bmp";   Mat imgToProcess = Highgui.imread(filename);   Still crashes. :/

Comment: That means that this file is not located there. Use `getexternalstoragedirectory` instead `/mnt/sdcard/` and check the path again.

Comment: Post code samples of your several attempts and their errors (edit your question). You might be misunderstanding and doing something wrong.